# Telerik OpenAccess linq Any<t> and Count() error with AND

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, telerik

I am working with Telerik OpenAccess entityframework and need to make `Any` work correctly. The following expression is needed but fails due to `Any`. `(Count(..)=0` also fails:

```
using (var context = new Data())
{
    var g = context.GetRxByDate(tencounter, groupid).ToList();

    foreach (var v in rxs)
    {
        //Telerik "Any" linq extension fails for &&

        if (g.Any(c => c.Cform == v.rx.Cform
                       && c.Cmedname == v.rx.Cmedname
                       && c.Csig == v.rx.Cmedname
                       && c.Idisp == v.rx.Idisp
                       && c.Nrefills == v.rx.Nrefills
                       && c.Tstop == null
                       && c.Groupid == v.encounter.groupid))
                {
```

Anyone know a solution or a work-around?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GrantWinney As far as I can see, there is no error message. It simply fails to return True despite all phrases seen to be true in the debugger.

Comment: @GrantWinney If it helps any, the backend server is PostgreSQL. Thanks.

Comment: The variable `g` has data in it, right? Try temporarily doing `var results = g.Where(c => ...).ToList();` using all the same conditions and see if you get 0 records or more than 0.

Comment: @GrantWinney Yes. g returns about 20 "records" as List<Rx> from a PostgreSQL function GetRxByDate(). Stepping through the foreach loop confirms in the debugger that v.rx does match items in List<Rx>, but Any fails to report this. ???

Comment: @GrantWinney I can't get Any (Telerik extension to work), but using Where() might be a good work-around? I'll try it.

Comment: @GrantWinney Yep. Where() with FirstOrDefault works perfectly. Thanks!